# Is there any way to estimate transformer's estimated remaining lifetime without testing the oil (or degree of polymerization)?

Tags: transformer, ac, electric-machine, distribution-network

The common parameter for transformer health monitoring is testing the oil and sediments (N.B., there might be others I don't know). The insulating strength of oil is decreased due to faults, overload, ambient humidity and temperature. So it might be possible to estimate the remaining lifetime by checking those. But I did not find any mathematical relationship related to this.

Comment: AFAIK there are mostly *empirical* relationship but if you look around there is research on the field. My idea is simply that testing oil is easier, just pick some from the oil tank (conservator). For online monitoring I've seen something like antenna for detecting sub-corona discharged (at the beginning of insulation failure)

Comment: If I can paraphrase your title - 'How to determine the expected life of a transformer without checking the condition of the single most important component that may cause it to fail?'

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio I checked some papers on transformer health monitoring based on corona discharge. Do these work on 11KV/440V distribution transformers? Or do they just work for high voltage transformers of substations?

Comment: @Neil_UK, sure :)

Answer (score 1):

There may be a way of doing it by measuring the changes in capacitance in the transformer.

[Here is a thesis on the subject](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.848.3942&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

> Initially we short all three phases both primary and secondary. We
> consider this one as one of the conducting plate and body is the other
> conducting plate. As we know oil is inside the transformer which
> separates body and the phases both primary and secondary. So we can
> consider this one as a two conducting plate capacitor. But in this
> case the area of two conducting plate is not equal like the
> conventional two parallel plate capacitor. Now take a multi-meter that
> can measure capacitance or any capacitor meter. Put one probe in body
> and other probe in shorted three phases (for three phases transformer)
> and take the value of capacitance shown in the display of the miter

Comment: SFRA (Sweep Frequency Response Analysis) can help to check mechanical damage in the windings among many problems and FDS (Frequency Domain Spectroscopy) helps in defining if the oil and/or the paper are moist/degraded or not. But, no one of them will tell the remaining lifetime of the transformer.

Answer (score 0):

You will not found any really deterministic way to compute the remaining lifetime of a transformer.

The only straightforward option is to use IEC 60076-7 to compute the thermal aging of the transformer, but it's all based on degree of polymerization.

If fact, there is no direct relation between oil dielectric withstanding or moisture content and the transformer failure. Dielectric failure is really scatter and, although you can know that the oil is in bad conditions, transformer can operate many years even with contaminated oil, it depends a lot on the electric/mechanical troubles it will be submitted (as short-circuit or lightning).